# Add SwingX Pallete in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, swingx

I am working with netbeans 7.2 and want to install swingX.I have install swingX 1.6.2 but its not working.
Thanking You.

Comment: Place swingx jar file on your classpath.

Comment: the current release version is 1.6.4 (with 1.6.5 looming to come out any day now :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: in the central maven I see already an 1.6.5: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.swinglabs.swingx%22

Comment: Also here is the announcment: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kschaefe/archive/2013/01/29/swingx-165-released

Comment: @Ibalazscs thanks for news, underestimated Karl's speed :-)

Answer (score 11):

The following steps are from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120121042921/http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingXIDE):

**Adding SwingX library to NetBeans:**

1. Open NetBeans, go to menu Tools > Library Manager and click "New
   Library...";
2. Type a name (could be "SwingX") and click Ok;
3. Select the Library that you created and, in the Classpath box (on the right), click "Add JAR/Folder...";
4. Then go to the folder where you downloaded swingx.jar file, select it and click "Add JAR/Folder" in this window.

Now the SwingX components are already available to you use in NetBeans. But, to use them in a project, do the following steps:

**Adding SwingX library to the Project Libraries:**

1. Right click on your project that you want to use the SwingX
   components and select Properties;
2. Select "Libraries" in the left box;
3. Click "Add Library..." and select the library that you created in Adding SwingX library to NetBeans ("SwingX", as I suggested);
4. Click "Add Library" and then Ok.

Now your project can use the SwingX components, but we already need to set the NetBeans's Palette to show the SwingX components.

**Adding the SwingX components to the NetBeans's Palette:**

1. Create (or open) a Java GUI Class Form. The Palette will appear;
2. Right click on the palette and select "Palette Manager...";
3. Click "New Category...", type a name (could be "SwingX" again) and click Ok;
4. Select the category that you created in the box and click "Add from Library...";
5. Select the library that you created in Add SwingX library to NetBeans ("SwingX", as I suggested) and click "Next >";
6. On the next screen, click in the box and type Ctrl+A (to select all items) and click "Next >" again;
7. Finally select the category that you created on the third step of this topic ("SwingX", as I suggested);
8. Click Finish and then Close.

Comment: +1 for digging out the wiki backup :-) Looks slightly dated, though - afair, newer versions need the beaninfo jar for the builder (aka: palette) - not entirely sure about that, never using a visual builder myself

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answer is a bit dated, here are the steps I followed on NetBeans 7.3.1

**Adding SwingX Libraries to NetBeans (Not Needed if you're using Maven)**

1) Goto `Tools->Ant Libraries` and click `Add JAR/Folder` to add the SwingX jar file to the NetBeans classpath

**Making SwingX components available in the Palette View**

1) Open the Palette menu using `Window->Palette`

2) Click on a blank area at the bottom of this window (you may need to collapse sub windows) and select `Palette Manager`

3) Click on `New Category` and crate a SwingX folder

4 non-maven) If you **ARE NOT** using Maven, click `Add from Library` and add the SwingX jar from above.

4 maven) If you **ARE** using Maven, click `Add from JAR` and select the SwingX jar from the maven classpath.  You can find the jar maven downloaded at `HOME_DIR\.m2\repository\org\swinglabs\swingx\1.6.x\`

4) Select all the controls available, click Next then select SwingX from the categories and click Finish